# How to pass a parameter to `_T()`?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I've the following code:

```
CString port = m_HOST_PORT.GetString();

ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, _T("cmd.exe"), 
     _T("/k \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_45\\bin\\java\" -cp C:\\Users\\foobar\\workspace\\IEC60870\\bin main.CApp %s",
     (LPCTSTR)(port)), SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

When I run the snippet-code (a small part from a bigger code), then the command prompt window appear with the following text: *Unknown: %s*. Clearly, `_T("%s", (LPCTSTR)(port))` doesn't work or I don't know how to use it in a correct way.

How can I pass a parameter, like `(LPCTSTR)(port)`, to `_T()`?

P.S.:

Typing it by hand, like:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, _T("cmd.exe"),
     _T("/k \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_45\\bin\\java\" -cp C:\\Users\\foobar\\workspace\\IEC60870\\bin main.CApp 4711"),
     SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

will work here.

Comment: `_T()` is only a macro that works with character literal sequences. I'm pretty sure your question is a duplicate.

Comment: You should have got a "too many actual parameters" warning for the macro use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_T()` is not a function, it is a macro that expands to either nothing or to `L` depending on whether the unicode macros are defined or not; [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dybsewaf.aspx).

If unicode is defined (`_UNICODE` and `UNICODE`) then;

```
_T("hello world");
```

becomes

```
L"hello world";
```

Else it is just `"hello world";`

To use the usual `printf` style of formatting, just use `sprintf` or `snprintf`; the corresponding macro to support the `_T()` is [`_stprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf.aspx) that will either be `sprintf` or `swprintf` depending of the unicode macro. For explicit buffer size control, you can use [`_sntprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93.aspx).

---

Sample usage (buffer overruns etc. not considered);

```
TCHAR buffer[1024] = {}; // make sure the buffer is large enough
TCHAR format[] = _T("/k \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_45\\bin\\java\" -cp C:\\Users\\foobar\\workspace\\IEC60870\\bin main.CApp %s");
::_stprintf(buffer, format, (LPCTSTR)(port));
ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, _T("cmd.exe"),
  buffer, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: @aGer There is no problem.  `(LPCTSTR)(port)` is fine. it will convert to `LPCSTR` for the ANSI version and to `LPCWSTR` for the UNICODE version.